# Вставка в очередь по приоритету!

Tags: c++

подредактируйте пожалуйста вставку! не пойму где неправильно переставляю указатели!

```
//Параметры: pbq - "указатель" начала очереди,
//      peq - "указатель" конца очереди, newEl - новый элемент
void INSERT(TPQueue* &pbq,TPQueue* &peq, TElQ newEl)
{
    TPQueue* el=new TPQueue; //Формируем новый элемент очереди
    el->info=newEl;
    el->next=NULL;
    TPQueue *wp,*pp;
    wp=pbq;
    pp=NULL;
    while(wp!=NULL&&wp->info>el->info){
        pp=wp;
        wp=wp->next;
    }
    if (pp==NULL) {    //Если очередь НЕпустая
        peq=el;
        pbq=el;}
    else{
        pp->next=el;       //Элемент заносим в очередь
        el->next=wp;
        while(wp->next!=NULL)
            wp=wp->next;
        peq=wp;

    }
}
```

Comment: или подскажите что неправильно, а я потом сам поменяю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Юра1996](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996), насколько помню, я уже писал, как эту задачу решать лучше.

Но если настаиваете, то вот так можно включать элементы в упорядоченный по убыванию поля `info` односвязный список, сохраняя порядок между элементами с одинаковым `info` и поддерживая указатели на его первый и последний элементы.

```
void insert (TPQueue *&pbq, TPQueue *&peq, int info)
{
  TPQueue *el = new TPQueue;
  el->next = 0;
  el->info = info;

  if (!pbq) 
    pbq = peq = el;
  else if (info > pbq->info) {
    el->next = pbq;
    pbq = el;
  } else if (info <= peq->info) {
    peq->next = el;
    peq = el;
  } else {
    TPQueue *t;
    for (t = pbq; t->next->info >= info; t = t->next);
    el->next = t->next;
    t->next = el;
  }

}
```

Пример вызова

```
void qprint (TPQueue *pbq)
{
  while (pbq) {
    cout << pbq->info  << '\n';
    pbq = pbq->next;
  }
}

int main () {
  TPQueue *pb = 0, *pe;

  insert(pb, pe, 3);
  insert(pb, pe, 11);
  insert(pb, pe, 1);
  insert(pb, pe, 2);
  insert(pb, pe, 2);
  insert(pb, pe, 3);
  insert(pb, pe, 11);

  qprint(pb);
}
```

Надеюсь, теперь разберетесь.